# For simple tasks, Is using C# DataTable overkill?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm currently writing a method to read a CSV file and return it's content.

The contents being header (columns' names) + data, I was thinking about using a DataTable to store the result.

Would it be performant? Knowing I will mainly just read the whole content to send it over another system (FYI: a FoxPro one, which is out of this question's scope).

What could I otherwise use? (my goal is to have a somewhat maintenance/readability friendly code).

For the time being I just use a List of List of strings.

```
var returnValue = new List<List<string>>();

var csv = CSV;

var regexp = new Regex("(?:;|^)\"((?:[^\"]|(?:\"\"))*)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var lines = csv.Split('\n');
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var matches = regexp.Matches(line);
    returnValue.Add(matches.Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\"\"", "\""))
                           .ToList());
}

return returnValue;
```

Comment: There is a small library about to help profile this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/26/benchmarking-made-easy.aspx ....I'd suggest taking a look.

Comment: I avoid `DataTable` like the plague. I would create a class to represent the structure of the CSV and go from there.

Comment: @rhughes Why do you say that?

Comment: I agree with @rhughes `DataTable` and `DataSet` I avoid as much as possible [link](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx)

Comment: @Alberto It keeps the code cleaner, easier to manage and read and fixed types over 'unknown string based indexes' are more refined.

Comment: @rhughes & Secret Squirrel is DataTable really that bad? Any indication what's so wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Your content is headers and rows. Or in short a DataTable. Like many programming questions you have to decide if it is worth the extra work have cleaner code.

You mention you just read a cvs and sent it to another piece of software. It seems rather a big overkill to create classes for this. On the other had if you expect changes or extensions in the near future, it might still be worth the extra effort now.

In short:

- You are **not** using the DataTable structure incorrect.
- Should you use it? Depends on the scope of the project.